# OS-prober is taking a really long time

Tags: grub2, os-prober

Any time I update my GRUB configuration or install a kernel update that has the update manager update my grub configuration, the os-prober part of the configuration hangs for sometimes 10-20 minutes. I have a few partitions including windows, Ubuntu, and some other Linux distros. I will post a list of my partitions below just in case that helps. Any of my other distrobutions will run os-prober just fine and quickly, but in Ubuntu it finds the Ubuntu vmlinuz files and all very quickly and then hangs for a really long time before it will discover my other partitions with little to no disk activity during this time. Once it finishes though, everything is fine, but it is really annoying for os-prober to be taking this long and I know it shouldn't be.

`sda

├─sda1 vfat   DELLUTILITY 
├─sda2 ntfs   Recovery
├─sda3 ntfs   OS
├─sda4 
├─sda5 ext4   Ubuntu      /
├─sda6 swap               [SWAP]
├─sda7 ext4   Arch Linux 
├─sda8 ext4
└─sda9 ext4   Stash       /media/stash`

sda4 is an extended partition including all the Linux partitions on partitions sda5, sda7, and sda8. sda6 is swap and sda9 is shared file storage. The boot loader is installed to the MBR with the configurations in Ubuntu's partition of sda5